# Como configurar acesso externo no IIS Express do VS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis

Tenho um webservice em asp.net mvc 4 rodando no meu pc local, se eu faço `http://localhost:14807` funciona blzinha, mas se eu faço, `http://192.168.1.105:14807` que é ele mesmo não funciona, o mesmo acontece se eu tento acessar de outro dispositivo. Estou usando o VS 2013.

Como faço para habilitar o acesso externo ?

Comment: Encontrei algumas opções nesse link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3313616/iis-express-enable-external-request

Comment: No primeiro caso, você está acessando utilizando a porta 14807, no segundo caso está faltando o número de porta: `http://192.168.1.105:14807`. Tentarei elaborar uma resposta mais clara.

Comment: @VítorSubhi sim, no segundo caso nao informei a porta mas estou tentando com a porta tbm, vou editar o post pra coloca-la.

Comment: Resolvido, fiz exatamente como no link: http://johan.driessen.se/posts/Accessing-an-IIS-Express-site-from-a-remote-computer